# flot chart not drawing from ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flot

I am trying to draw a flot chart using some Ajax data which is as follows when I `console.log` it :

```
[{ label:"series1",
          data : [[1459555200000,200],[1459987200000,440]],last:true}]
```

but when I use it as data in flot chart, the chart is blank , whereas if I hardcode it it runs great.

My code is:

```
$.get('chartgadmin.php',
    function (d) {
    console.log(d); 
        var data = [d];
        var labelColor = chart.css('color');
        var options = {
            colors: chart.data('color').split(','),
            series: {
                shadowSize: 0,
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: false,
                    fill: true
                },
                curvedLines: {
                    apply: true,
                    active: true,
                    monotonicFit: false
               }
            },
            legend: {
                container: $('#flot-visitors-legend')
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%d %b",
                font: {color: labelColor}
            },
            yaxis: {
                font: {color: labelColor}
            },
            grid: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                color: labelColor,
                hoverable: true
            }
        };
        chart.width('100%');
        // Create chart
        var plot = $.plot(chart, data, options);
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use JSON.parse(d),i had some how same problem,i was solved by this.

Comment: you just saved the life @SagarR. Thanks a zillion

Comment: shall I put as answer ?

Comment: i have posted as answer,please mark it as answer so other can also get it easily. Thanks.

Comment: sure , in another 3 mins I will

Comment: this solved the problem for 1 series , not for multiple :(

Comment: can I have jsfiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=r5oNjhOAmr

Comment: jsfiddle link is not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satyadoorva/5cL68p1o/

Comment: Code seems good in jsfiddle,but I am not able to get any data in that jsfiddle,there is nothing to check,i mean, can I have working chart in that jsfiddle? otherwise i will not able to inspect it properly.

Comment: the data is :     [{"label":"Activ8 Studio","data":[[1459555200000,200],[1459987200000,440]],"last":true},{"label":"Zumba With Breakbeat","data":[[1459555200000,140],[1459987200000,0],[1459382400000,180]],"last":true}]

Comment: If you will put alert() and inspect the data after JSON.parse(d),you will get all data in perfect format,i think there should be some problem in plotting.do let me know if you find that solution or need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not parsing your argument  **" d "** in chart readable format,so whenever you are passing hardcode data it works fine,but the object which you are passing directly will get by the chart datasource,so you have to use,

```
JSON.parse(d);
```